# How to set a Vue variable equal to a function argument?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, osc

I am making a web app that can send and receive OSC data via a node.js server. That's all working fine. But I want to use Vue.js for the front and here I get a problem with declaring a function. When I am using only JavaScript it's working well.

Javascript:

```js
import osc from "osc";
var port = new osc.WebSocketPort({
  url: "ws://localhost:8083" //localhost:8083 online server 178.62.209.37:8083
});
port.open();

var message = []

OSCMessage();

function OSCMessage() {
  port.on("message", function(oscMessage) {
    //console.log(oscMessage);
    OSCMessages(oscMessage);
  });
}

function OSCMessages(oscMessage) {
  message = oscMessage;
  console.log(message);
}
```

But when I try to put it into Vue, I get an error in the console, even when I try it with `this.OSCMessages`:

> OSCMessages is not defined

Vue code:

```js
import osc from "osc";
var port = new osc.WebSocketPort({
  url: "ws://localhost:8083" //localhost:8083 online server 178.62.209.37:8083
});
port.open();

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: 60,
      message: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    OSCMessage: function() {
      port.on("message", function(oscMessage) {
        //console.log(oscMessage); // this console log is working great.
        this.OSCMessages(oscMessage)
      });
    },
    OSCMessages: function(oscMessage) {
      this.message = oscMessage
      console.log(this.message.address);
    },
  },
}
```

My goal is to make the Vue variable `message` equal to the `oscMessage`, so that I can continue to use the `oscMessage` data in Vue. I think it has something to do with scoping in Vue. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues.

1) If you don't use an es6 arrow function as a callback, then `this` will not refer to the Vue instance.

Change this:

```js
port.on("message", function (oscMessage) {    
   this.OSCMessages(oscMessage)
});
```

to:

```js
port.on("message", (oscMessage) => {    
   this.OSCMessages(oscMessage)
});
```

2) These both appear to be methods, not computeds.  Or at least `OSCMessages` is being called like a method. You can't pass arguments to computeds.

Change:

```js
computed: {
```

to

```js
methods: {
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about this.  You'll need to run `this.OSCMessage()` to register the port listener.  You can do that in the `created()` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your help! it's working now exactly as I want. I can make the OSC data visible via Vue.js. I used  "" beforeMount()"" but maybe is it via ""created()"" a better option?

Comment: Hi Dominique, you're welcome- I'm glad it's working.  To your question, `created` is a good place to do things that are purely data related, whereas `mounted` and `beforeMount` often have more to do with DOM-related manipulations.  They are specially related to the status of the DOM after the data is ready.

Comment: Hi, Dan. Yeah I already read something about that I will change it to `created()` maybe it works even better than ;) Thanks again for your help!